# How to implement PushMon on Ruby site

Tags: monitoring, ruby, network-monitoring

I am looking to implement PushMon on a number of sites using Ruby Padrino. I have the following piece of code from the PushMon site. Where would I place said code. I was thinking of adding it to the controller get for session/new but then again I could be completely wrong.

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

urlString = 'http://pshmn.com/WwFnvY'
begin
    Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse(urlString))
rescue
    # log error
end
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.pushmon.com/cms/sample-code

> For PushMon to work, you need to access the PushMon URL on a regular
>   schedule. This means you will most likely need to make some code or
>   script changes on your end. For example, if you want PushMon to
>   monitor your Bash script, call the PushMon URL at the end of Bash
>   script. Below you will find sample code that can help you get started.
>   If you have any suggestions, comments, additions, feel free to contact
>   us.

the code you posted is gistfile1.rb source code

Look like you need to contact them...
http://www.pushmon.com/cms/contact